# How to get to the 2nd level JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am new to Scala. Need help with this code

```
val jsonMappedLines = decodedLines.map( x => {
  var dataMap:Map[String, Any] = Map()
  val payload = new JsonParser().parse(x._2).getAsJsonObject()
  val setObj = payload.entrySet()
  val itr = setObj.iterator()
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
  val entry = itr.next();
  try {
    dataMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsDouble())
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => dataMap.put(entry.getKey(),   entry.getValue().getAsString())
    }
  }
  (x._1, dataMap)
})
```

It works when my x is

```
(MqttClient:aabbccddee,{"myName": "Arduino DHT22","temperatureF": 80,"temperatureC": 26,"humidity": 23})
```

But fails when the x is

```
(MqttClient:aabbccddee,{ "d": { "myName": "Arduino DHT22", "temperatureF": 80, "temperatureC": 26, "humidity": 24 }})
```

Notice the "d". Error is a Json parse exception.

Comment: It seems you are trying to manually parse. There are lots of libraries in Scala that will parse JSON document into a case class. Any reason you aren't using one of those?

Comment: From what library does new `JsonParser()` come from?

Comment: New to Scala. Don't know about the other Scala libraries. com.google.gson.JsonParser